# Linear Algebra 2 practice Exams

Tags: linear-algebra

My Linear Algebra course followed Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler book with emphasis on Operators and less on matrix theory. I guessed you can call it Linear Algebra 2 but my university doesn't call it that. When I search for practice exams the focus is either on matrix theory or something about Hilbert Spaces which we didn't cover.

I would greatly appreciate any links to a similar course with exams posted, it would make studying for the final much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find some things on a website of mine for a past course, which also used Axler: http://math.berkeley.edu/~scanez/courses/math110/

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT, part 1: I post this as an individual, and not as a representative of the Department of Mathematics at Macquarie University.

[Here](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math235s212/exams.html) (but see below, EDIT part 2) are links to past exams for Math 235 at a university. The unit is half Calculus, half Linear Algebra. I'm not sure whether the Linear Algebra part aligns with what you've done, but I'm sure you'll be able to work that out. Note that solutions are not posted, just the exams.

EDIT, part 2: The link above appears to be broken. I believe it is possible to access old exams by going to the university website, finding your way to the Library pages, using the search function there, selecting "Past Exams" from a drop-down menu, and typing in (for example) Math235.

EDIT, part 3: I have been advised that the Library holdings are password-protected. My apologies.